# How many bytes were allocated by

Tags: c, pointers

How many bytes were allocated by double *p[10]; ?

I am wondering between 4 bytes (= 1 pointer size) and 10 x 4 bytes (= array of 10 pointers).

Comment: You may want to double-check the size of a pointer on your system. It could be 4 bytes, but these days it's more likely to be 8 (entirely depends on what you're working with, of course). I bring this up just in case you assumed 4-byte pointers, but it doesn't really change the substance of the question or the answer.

Comment: You can ask your compiler with `printf("The size is %zu bytes.\n", sizeof(double *[10]));`. Note that the identifier, `p`, was removed, leaving just an abstract type as the operand to `sizeof`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of ten pointers. It contains bogus values, and you should initialize it (maybe clearing it with `memset`).

On your machine, ten pointers need forty bytes.

On my desktop (x86-64 running [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) 20.04, using a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler) they need 80 bytes

On some microcontrollers (perhaps [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/)) a pointer could take just two bytes. In 2021 you would use some [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) for these.

See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and some C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better.

Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source C software like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

And study the source code of some open source C compiler coded in C, like [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCC).

Comment: Exactly.  The size is, in general, `10*sizeof(double*)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder how much space `p` takes, simply do:

```
printf("%zu", sizeof p);
```

If you want to know exactly what type it is, use this site https://cdecl.org/

In your case, `p` is not a pointer. It's an array of pointers. If you change to `double (*p)[10]` you will instead get a pointer to array.